# How to add photo to google contact?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to add photo to google contact, using python and gdata library.

```
contact = gd_client.GetContact('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/denisz.pol%40gmail.com/base/61839cbb8a335dbb')
gd_client.ChangePhoto('img.jpeg',contact)
```

But there is an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-03d065010e8f> in <module>()
----> 1 gd_client.ChangePhoto('img.jpeg',contact)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdata/contacts/client.py in change_photo(self, media, contact_entry_or_url, content_type, content_length, auth_token, **kwargs)
    253         ifmatch_header = None
    254         if isinstance(contact_entry_or_url, gdata.contacts.data.ContactEntry):
--> 255             photo_link = contact_entry_or_url.GetPhotoLink()
    256             uri = photo_link.href
    257             ifmatch_header = atom.client.CustomHeaders(

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'href'
```

If I add photo to contact "by hands" nothing will change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `contact_entry_or_url.GetPhotoLink()` is returning `None`, so `photo_link` is set to `None`. Hence `photo_link.href` causes that error. I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but maybe try `gd_client.AddPhoto('img.jpeg',contact)` instead of `gd_client.ChangePhoto('img.jpeg',contact)`.

Comment: @Ollie there is no function `AddPhoto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, strange but if we call `GetPhotLink()` outside the `ChangePhoto` function `href` attribute will not be `None`. So this code

```
gd_client.ChangePhoto('img.jpeg',contact.GetPhotoLink().href, content_type='image/*')
```

will change the photo.